# Can I use zbar and trim to fill a 6" gap at the bottom of siding for my shed/workshop?

Tags: siding

So I'd prefer to use 4x8' sheets of the siding as they're available and affordable. Because I want my walls as high as possible I'd prefer to use 96' studs but with the top and bottom plates that means it's too high for a normal 8' sheet with some overhanging the joists. Instead of buying all 9' sheets could I just buy some 6" trim and transition the siding to the trim with zbar?

[image]

Comment: What kind of siding are you thinking about using?  Most siding products I'm familiar with are meant to be installed over a sheathing (like OSB) & house wrap, and not directly attached to the studs.

Comment: plenty of types can be directly attached, eg hardieflex,

Comment: SmartSide 38 Series Primed Engineered Treated Wood Siding Panel is what I'm thinking of using.

Comment: Is Hardieflex different from Hardie plank?  Everything I've seen about the later says to install over plywood or OSB sheathing.

Comment: requrements for undelay may vary depending on where you are building, https://www.jameshardie.co.nz/web/assets/downloads/HardieFlex-Technical-Specification.pdf

Answer (score 1):

sure you can transition between different sidings with a Z flashing but you need blocking behind the transition.

Comment: Do you mean all along the seam? So, in my picture, I have the studs but nothing behind the actual seem at the transition. Could some simple blocking solve that?

Comment: Yes, 2x4 or 2x6's on edge, flush with the outside edge of the studs.  Just like you would install for hanging kitchen cabinets.